Display sns heatmap in Tkinter
In Tkinter GUI I have three Entry widgets that are used to enter numbers into nested for loops that create an array that is used to create a seaborn heatmap after hitting the "submit" button. The Entry widgets are in a frame and I would like to plot the heatmap centered in the GUI window below the frame. I can create the plot axis but the heatmap does not display. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()

def HPS(x,y,z): #HPS Function
    NUMX = int(x.get()) # No. of columns (x)
    NUMY = int(y.get()) # No. rows (y)
    NUMZ = int(z.get())# No. of levels (z)
    
    z = np.zeros((NUMZ)) # define number of levels
    conc = np.zeros((NUMZ, NUMY, NUMX)) #Create 3d conc array (z,y,x)

    for z in range(NUMZ):
      for y in range(NUMY):
         for x in range(NUMX):
             c = round(random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) ,2)
             conc[z,y,x] = c      # fill array with for loops
                 
    conc_sum = conc.sum(axis=0) # add the two z-levels together
    print(conc_sum)
    df_sum = pd.DataFrame(conc_sum) # Create dataframe of sum_conc array

    #Create heatmap and plot in Tkinter
    figure = Figure(figsize=(4, 4))
    ax = figure.subplots()
    sns.heatmap(df_sum,cmap='RdBu') # Create heatmap
    plt.ylim(0,NUMY) # Reverse y-axis coordinates   
    
    # Plot heatmap in Tkinter
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row =8, column=0, columnspan=3)
           
# HPS Tkinter GUI
root.geometry("400x400") # Set sizeof GUI
frame1 = Frame(root) #Create fame for input boxes   
frame1=LabelFrame(root, text='Frame 1', padx=10, pady=10)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Create input boxes and labels
label1 = Label(frame1, text='NUMX = ') 
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2 = Label(frame1, text='NUMY = ') 
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
label3 = Label(frame1, text='NUMZ = ') 
label3.grid(row=2, column=0)

#Enter data
x = Entry(frame1)    
y = Entry(frame1)
z = Entry(frame1)
x.grid(row=0, column = 2)
y.grid(row=1, column = 2)
z.grid(row=2, column = 2)

#Create submit button and call HPS function
myButton = Button(root, text='Submit', command = lambda:HPS(x,y,z))
myButton.grid(row = 5, column = 2)

root.mainloop()

I have tried a variety of different Tkinter code for displaying plots as suggested from different forums.

The following change in code within the HPS function created the heatmap:
#Create heatmap and plot in Tkinter
figure = Figure(figsize=(4, 4))
ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
sns.heatmap(df_sum,ax=ax,cmap='RdBu') # Create heatmap
plt.ylim(0,NUMY) # Reverse y-axis coordinates
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row =8, column=0, columnspan=3)

